# Use XMLIndex on column queries of a XMLTable

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, indexing

I am wondering if there is a way to make Oracle use an `XMLIndex` on a property when the property is resolved as a column of a table. For example, the following code would use the `XMLIndex` that I have specified but it will not do the same if I specify the column name:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable, XMLTABLE(
  '/foo' PASSING PAYLOAD COLUMNS
  res PATH './bar/text()'
) 
-- where res = 'abc';
where XMLExists('/foo/bar/text()="abc"]' PASSING PAYLOAD)
```

I would like to define views of such tables with many columns that should be easy to query. Currently I work around by using materialized views and indexing columns directly but I would very much prefer a solution that uses an `XMLIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more details google for `Structured Component to an XMLIndex Index`. 
And here little example.

1)Prep test structure.

```
create table xindex_example(a number, b xmltype);

insert into xindex_example values(1,xmltype('<root><x>
<a>1</a>
<b>2</b>
</x>
</root>'));
```

2) Create xmlindex with parameters.

```
CREATE INDEX xindex_example_idx ON xindex_example (b) INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLIndex
  PARAMETERS (q'~XMLTable my_test_group_tab
                 '/root/x'
                 columns a_val number path './a' ,  b_val number path './b'~');

  ;
```

Oracale automatically creates table my_test_group_tab but you cannot do the query from this table directly. (`ORA-30967: operation directly on the Path Table is disallowed`)

You can do the desc my_test_group_tab to see the structure.

3) Create b+tree index on the create table

```
create index my_test_group_tab_idx on my_test_group_tab(a_val);
```

4) And test it.

```
  select * from (
  select x.* from xindex_example,xmltable('/root/x' passing b columns a_val number path './a' ,  b_val number path './b') x)
  where a_val=1;
```

5) Execution plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                       |     1 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |                       |     1 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MY_TEST_GROUP_TAB     |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | MY_TEST_GROUP_TAB_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID | XINDEX_EXAMPLE        |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```